# Python global behaviour

Tags: python, global

In a script which process 500k links on XML validation and relaxng i tried to count cases in myFunc(). If i use global variables i had to mark them global in myFunc() before i can change them. When i printed out the values of them in myFunc() i can see that the value is changed to 1,2,3,4 and so on.
But when i print out the values in run() i get not the changed values. All three variables are 0 in run(), like before changing them in myFunc().

I know that there are serious better ways to do this job. But my question is why the changed globals are not changed anymore in run() and if there is a possibilty to realize this?

Has it to do with the multiprocessing?

```
valid = 0
excpt = 0
relaxerr = 0

def myFunc(link):
   try:
      global valid
      valid += 1
      print valid
      doc = etree.parse(urllib2.urlopen(link))
   except Exception, e:
      global except
      excpt += 1
      print excpt
      with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
         f.write('%s\n' % e)
      return

   if not RELAXNG.validate(doc):
      global relaxerr
      relaxerr += 1
      print relaxerr
      with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
         f.write('%s\n' % RELAXNG.error_log)
      return

   ....
   do stuff for valid ....

def run():
   ...
   pool.map_async(myFunc, links, 64)
   pool.wait()


   print valid
   print excpt
   print relaxerr
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109776/changing-global-variable-when-multiprocessing-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run` function runs in the first process, while the calls to `myFunc` are done in **different** processes, which do not share the address space.

What you are doing would work with threads(probably using some locks...), since they *do* share the address space.

If you want to use `multiprocessing` you have to use some explicit process communication between the processes. For example you could use a pipe, queue or manager(see the `multiprocessing` documentation).

Comment: I was thinking on different scopes. But different processes, that makes sense. Thank you very much.