# How do you share a variable between two processes in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two processes, one adds jobs to a queue and the other takes them off the same queue and runs them. This should work as expected and I'm not sure why the `worker` never gets any jobs. Here's my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from Queue import Queue
import time

q = Queue()

def queuer():
    while True:
        q.put("JOB")
        print "Adding JOB"
        time.sleep(1)

def worker():  
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            item = q.get()
            print "Running", item
        else:
            print "No jobs"
            time.sleep(1)

a = Process(target=queuer)
a.start()

b = Process(target=worker)
b.start()
```

Comment: each process has its own copy of the queue. There is another stackoverflow thread that discusses this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109776/changing-global-variable-when-multiprocessing-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to pass the Queue as an argument to both processes.
2. You should use multiprocessing.Queue, not Queue.Queue (which are for Threads)

This code works for me:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def queuer(q):
    while True:
        q.put("JOB")
        print "Adding JOB"
        time.sleep(1)

def worker(q):  
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            item = q.get()
            print "Running", item
        else:
            print "No jobs"
            time.sleep(1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    a = Process(target=queuer, args=(q,))
    b = Process(target=worker, args=(q,))
    a.start()
    b.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the Queue object from the multiprocessing namespace. It's described here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

So I adapted your code. I only made 2 changes:
 - Use multiprocessing Queue 
 - Avoid globals and pass the queue as a parameter to the worker and queuer (this is not needed but it's good practice to keep everything tidy)

```
# use the Queue from the multiprocessing namespace!
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

q = Queue()

def queuer(q):
    while True:
        q.put("JOB")
        print "Adding JOB"
        time.sleep(1)

def worker(q):  
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            item = q.get()
            print "Running", item
        else:
            print "No jobs"
            time.sleep(1)

a = Process(target=queuer, args =(q,))
a.start()

b = Process(target=worker, args = (q,))
b.start()
```